# How can I take url to a file, which is on dropbox, programmatically?

Tags: django, python-3.x, dropbox-api

Here is my code:

```
from main import settings
import dropbox


def create(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        image = request.FILES['image']
        dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(settings.DROPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN)
        imageName = "{}.{}".format(uuid.uuid4(), image._name.split('.')[-1])
        path = settings.DROPBOX_FOLDER + imageName
        response = dbx.files_upload(image, path)
```

How can I take url of image in a variable 'image_url'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the [sharing_create_shared_link](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.org/en/master/moduledoc.html#dropbox.base.DropboxBase.sharing_create_shared_link) method in the [Dropbox Python SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/python#install).

The basic idea would likely be something like:

```
dbx.sharing_create_shared_link(path)
```